# Main Div expand dynamically

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to set up a simple layout for my homepage.
This is how I want it to look like:

[image: layout]

Unfortunately, I've difficulties specifying the size for the `main` div. I want it to expand dynamically, both the height and the width. So it should "fill" the rest of the content, not filled by `menu` and `footer`.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>Link 1</li>
                <li>Link 2</li>
                <li>Link 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
           Text...
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.nav, .content{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.nav{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.main{
    height: 100%; /* something like 100% - 50px (height of footer) */
    width: 100%; /* something like 100% - 200px (width of menu) */
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #aabbcc;
}
.footer{
    background-color: #ff9999
}
```

You can find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/48q5f4u9/3/

Comment: pls set the min-height:auto; in main css

Comment: @Arun: Thanks, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First at all reset:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0}
```

After use `100%` on `body, html` tags and main container `.container`:

```
html,body, .container {
    height:100%;
}
```

Then use `calc()` to set the dimensions, like:

```
.main{
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #aabbcc;
}
```

#### [DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48q5f4u9/5/)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about calc() in CSS.

Comment: glad to help U @user1170330

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sabipu/48q5f4u9/4/)

This is one simple way to make content dynamic , setting float to sidebar. 
but i think you need to make more changes , set footer at bottom ( footer will be always at the end of the page ) and by this way you can make things look more attractive.

Hope this helps, let me know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can used sticky footer and absolute and border-box for main and nav and play with padding because they have a defined size:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.main, .nav { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    top: 0;
    width:200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #1abc9c;
    z-index: 1;
}
.main {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 50px 200px;
    background: #3498db;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.container:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
}
.footer, .container:after {
      height: 50px; 
}
.footer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        Text...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```